# Opengl Equivalent to Texture Blending?

Tags: opengl, graphics, directx

Is there equivalent functionality to Directx's texturing blending? [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206241(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb206241%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It basically blends several textures together before applying it onto the mesh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From scanning through that page, I believe you can do all of that in a fragment shader. You can bind multiple textures, sample them all in your shader, and combine the results at your hearts desire.

It looks similar to functionality that OpenGL used to have in the fixed function pipeline. My old version of the red book (OpenGL Programming Guide) has chapters on "Multitexturing" and "Texture Combiner Functions". This is still available if you use the compatibility profile. But IMHO, this is a great example of where squeezing certain kinds of functionality into the fixed pipeline looked very cumbersome, while doing the same thing in shaders is much easier and more flexible.

Comment: Yes it's possible with glsl shaders but unless I use several switch statements and a loop inside of the shader (which isn't that efficient) i'll end up having 1000s of shaders. In order to get the same flexibility.

Comment: 1000s of shaders because you want to combine the textures in so many different ways? If you do the same thing with fixed function, you'll probably get a lot of shaders as well. You just don't see them. I don't think anybody has made graphics hardware that directly implements a fixed pipeline in a long time. When you use the fixed pipeline, you just leave it up to the driver to generate the shaders.

Comment: I was thinking there might be another solution though, such as having some sort of blend function `mix(srcColor, dstColor, alpha) + mix(srcColor, dstColor, alpha)` to emulate the glBlendFunc. Which would only be some floating point multiplcations rather than switch statements ?

Comment: `mix (...)` implements one very specific blend equation: (srcColor * a + (1.0 - dstColor) * a), so you are back to square one if you do that. GL has had register/texture combiners for years, they were useful to implement rudimentary programmability back in the days of the fixed-function pipeline but they are worthless now. If you really want what you are describing, you could use subroutines.

Comment: Well i would want to implement the glBlendFunc functionality, but instead of the inputs being GL_SRC_COLOR and all that, it would simply be 1s and 0s. But i'm not entirely sure how to do that kind of blending. For example if I set GL_SRC_COLOR to zero, the output will be black regardless of the other parameters for the first multiplications part `(a1 * b1 * c1 * d1) + (a2 * b2 * c2 * d2)` where `a1` would be something like `srcColor * srcColorController1 + (1 - srcColorController1)`.